# How to put an icon in a MenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0

Is there a way to put an icon next to the text in a MenuItem?

I use the following code to display a popup menu when the user right clicks in a user control:

```
 ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
 MenuItem item = new MenuItem("test", OnClick);
 menu.MenuItems.Add(item);
 menu.Show(this, this.PointToClient(MousePosition));
```

I would like to put a icon to the left of the "test" string in the popup menu so that the user more easily recognizes it. Is there a way to do this other than by setting the OwnerDraw property to true (thus requiring me to completely draw the menu item myself, like it is done in this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/cs_menus.aspx)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you use `ContextMenuStrip` with `ToolStripMenuItem` instead? In which case, you can set `ToolStripMenuItem.Image`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using ContextMenuStrip and add ToolStripMenuItems to it.

If you have to use MenuItem, you will have to do it through the DrawItem event with the OwnerDraw property set to true.

Comment: ContextMenuStrip certainly does the job. I did no know that it existed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This was fixed 6 years ago with the .NET 2.0 release.  It acquired the ToolStrip classes.  The code is very similar:

```
        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem("test");
        item.Image = Properties.Resources.Example;
        item.Click += OnClick;
        menu.Items.Add(item);
        menu.Show(this, this.PointToClient(MousePosition));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are tied to `MenuItem`, then I've found the solution to be like this one:

```
var dropDownButton = new ToolBarButton();
dropDownButton.ImageIndex = 0;
dropDownButton.Style = ToolBarButtonStyle.DropDownButton;

var mniZero = new MenuItem( "Zero", (o, e) => DoZero() );
mniZero.OwnerDraw = true;
mniZero.DrawItem += delegate(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
    double factor = (double) e.Bounds.Height / zeroIconBmp.Height;
    var rect = new Rectangle( e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y,
                         (int) ( zeroIconBmp.Width * factor ),
                         (int) ( zeroIconBmp.Height * factor ) );
    e.Graphics.DrawImage( zeroIconBmp, rect );
};

var mniOne = new MenuItem( "One", (o, e) => DoOne() );
mniOne.OwnerDraw = true;
mniOne.DrawItem += delegate(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
    double factor = (double) e.Bounds.Height / oneIconBmp.Height;
    var rect = new Rectangle( e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y,
                     (int) ( oneIconBmp.Width * factor ),
                     (int) ( oneIconBmp.Height * factor ) );
    e.Graphics.DrawImage( oneIconBmp, rect );
};

dropDownButton.DropDownMenu = new ContextMenu( new MenuItem[]{
    mniZero, mniOne,
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me -- mainly i had to implement the `MeasureItem` event... also had to draw the text and selection rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Use ContextMenuStrip control, in that you can do that either it in the designer, by clicking on the item and selecting "Set image...", or programmatically by changing the Image property of the ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: @Bolu - Have a look at this link- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.icon.aspx

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem does not have such a property at least not in .Net 2.0

Comment: @BaGi - Hava look at this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.icon.aspx

Comment: @Bibhu, your link is for `System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem` normally used in WPF.. And where is the upvote come from?

Comment: @Bibhu: the link you mentioned refers to .Net 4.0 while I am using 2.0.