# How can I add an icon to a MenuItem?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put an icon in a MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623672/how-to-put-an-icon-in-a-menuitem)

I would like to put a door-and-arrow icon next to an Exit menu item. Is this possible? I'm sure it is, because I've seen it in other places before.

Comment: For WPF - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.icon.aspx

Comment: I'm using WinForms and I'd like to add that I don't want to use MenuStrip. I've tried that but it doesn't look like the system menu style; it looks like Office 2007 or something.

Comment: So you've seen - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623672/how-to-put-an-icon-in-a-menuitem then?

Comment: I've looked at it and the only possible solution here was listed here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4332/Putting-Images-Next-To-MenuItems-In-A-Menu-in-C but it looks ugly and unnatural. I would like it to look like the Vista/XP system menu.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. It must be, because you've seen it in other places before. It's also been answered in [How to put an icon in a MenuItem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6623672/62576) and particularly well in an answer to a similar question - [linked answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10672152/62576).

Comment: I kind of meant the OwnerDraw technique that looks ugly and unnatural. I'd like it to look like a regular menu. (e.g. Notepad-style)

Comment: What type of menu are you using if you aren't using `MenuStrip`?

Comment: I'm using MainMenu... You get it by adding it in the Choose Controls menu in the toolbox by right-clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an open source library called VistaMenu and it looks like just what I'm looking for. It is not custom drawn and it is inherited from the native menus.

http://wyday.com/vistamenu/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2012, it should be really simple to add an icon to the menu using the designer.

Right-click on the menu-item you want to add the icon to and select Set Image.[image: Screenshot of menu to set an image]

I don't recall if this option is available in previous versions of Visual Studio, but would image there should be an easy way through the IDE to set it.