# How to make a NotifyIcon() menu like you right click on window's title bar

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

[image: menu]

I want to make a menu like in the above picture in NotifyIcon's ContextMenu using WinForms.

I tried `ContextMenuStrip()`, but I found the style is different to `ContextMenu()` (e.g. the highlighted item), and only a few other tray icons use `ContextMenuStrip()` style. And if I use `ContextMenu()`, there is no FontStyle or Icon.

Is it possible to call that cross icon using a simple statement like `ToolTipIcon.Info`?  What is the easiest way to make a `MenuItem`'s label have bold font, and a cross icon in NotifyIcon's context menu? (I want use the same highlight style that in the picture)

Comment: If it were on WPF you could have many more options of customizing this.

Comment: @Tony At first, I use WinForm because this is a notify icon only application, and use WPF will increase process memory from 22 to 31.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put an icon in a MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623672/how-to-put-an-icon-in-a-menuitem)